# Combine same city with different spelling into 1

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a feed with information about companies. I import data from this feed to Drupal.
One of the field is City, and very often same city is spelled differently in that feed.

f.x. Copenhagen will be spelled like that:

1. København
2. København Ø
3. KBH
4. Kobenhavn

**My task**

I want to make a view categorised by cities and here the issue appear. I have multiple categories for the same city.

**What I'm looking for**

I would like to have possibility to define that 'København Ø', 'KBH' and 'Kobenhavn' are equal to 'København'.
I expect that city 'KBH' will be either converted or get an alias as København.

Comment: How do you import your data? You could use [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and [Feeds Tamper](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper). With Feeds Tamper you can manipulate your import data.

Comment: Another way would be creating a taxonomy list of all cities. First level your favorite spelling and second level all synonyms. With [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) you could now add your parent term as a field.

Comment: @huelfe I will try with taxonomy and see if I can deal with it.
I use Feeds Tamper, however I do not want to hardcode cities there, I believe taxonomy could be the solution.

Comment: This module may help but it depends a bit on your specific use case: https://www.drupal.org/project/term_merge